# Drag and drop a file to org buffer to insert a link to this file

Tags: microsoft-windows, org-link, hyperlinks, drag-and-drop

On Windows it is possible to create a link holding the `Meta` (Alt) key while dragging a file.

Is it possible to create a link to a file when it is dragged from an Explorer over to emacs holding the Meta key?

I know Onenote suports this behaviour, although you can choose to insert the whole file or just link to it.

Using dired (`Ctrl-x d`) to navigate to the file and copy it's name with `w` is a bit cumbersome. One has to add the path to the file manually. May there be also a better way to do this?

Comment: The usal way is to do `org-store-link` (the recommended binding in the Org mode manual is `C-c l`) on the file (or its directory entry) and then `org-insert-link` (recommended binding: `C-c C-l`) in your org file. I imagine it would be possible to associate these actions with a D-D operation, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Nice! I did not expect `org-store-link` to work in dired. I wil use this till I find how to drag and drop. Also I found the org-attach function useful although more sofisticated.